# How to dynamically create label on run time in asp.net c# to a particular place on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web page and in that I want to show data on label. The data will be shown through a SQL connection. I know how to create labels but I don't know how to create them to a particular place of web page.

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 6):

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>

// Create a Label object
Label dynamicLabel = new Label();
div1.Controls.Add(dynamicLabel );
```

---

In this code add one css class..

```
<div id="div1" class="location" runat="server"></div>
```

and in your styles.css add this code...

```
.location
{
margin-left: 30px
margin-top: 30px
}
```

you can also use other attributes...

Answer (score 3):

You can put the `label in desired place in html by making that html element server accessible`. You can put id in that html tag and make it runat = "server" to make the html elements server accessible.

**In html**

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
```

**In code behind.**

```
div1.Controls.Add(new Label());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>

// Create a Label object
div1.Controls.Add(new Label());
```